# Ninject dependencies that are InRequestScope are not disposed

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-mvc-5

This question has been asked many times before, but for the life of me I can not get Ninject to dispose services that are InRequestScope. I have looked at all the answers and most of them tell the user to use `Ninject.MVC3` or `OnePerRequestHttpModule`. I am using `Ninject.MVC5`.

Here is how to get to where I am:

Using VS2013

- Add new project (ASP.NET Web application)
- Choose MVC and no authentication
- Add NuGet reference to Ninject.MVC5
- Add an interface to project:

  ```
  public interface IBlah : IDisposable
  {
      void DoSomething();
  }
  ```
- Add an implementation for the interface:

  ```
  public class Blah : IBlah
  {
      private static int _count;

      public Blah()
      {
          _count++;
          Debug.WriteLine("Blah nr {0} created", _count);
      }

      public void DoSomething()
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("DoSomething called");
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
          _count--;
          Debug.WriteLine("Blah disposed. Still left {0}", _count);
      }
  }
  ```
- Open up home controller and add the following ivar and constructor:

  ```
  private readonly IBlah _blah;

  public HomeController(IBlah blah)
  {
      _blah = blah;
  }
  ```
- Add the following to `Index` action:

  ```
  _blah.DoSomething();
  ```
- Open NinjectWebCommon and add the following line to `RegisterServices` method

  ```
  kernel.Bind<IBlah>().To<Blah>().InRequestScope();
  ```
- Debug the project and look at Debug output you will see (among system messages)

  ```
  "Blah nr 1 created"
  "DoSomething called"
  ```
- Hit refresh in the browser and you will see

  ```
  "Blah nr 2 created"
  "DoSomething called"
  ```
- Nothing gets output for disposing, also breakpoint inside Dispose is never hit.

My test solution can be downloaded here: http://www.upload.ee/files/4044477/NinjectTest.zip.html

**What the hell am I doing wrong???**

---

**UPDATE 15 May 2014**

There is now a new version (3.2.2) of `Ninject.Web.Common` package available for NuGet that has fixed the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that is related to this ninject issue:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/132#issuecomment-42459686

Answer (score 0):

A good article (ignore the name) covering why:

http://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/How-Ninject-inadvertently-made-the-case-for-SOLID